# There exists z with 0<|z|< delta and e^{1/z}=w.

Tags: complex-analysis

> The function $f(z)=e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. By the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, for any complex number $w$, there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}$ with $\lim_{n→∞}z_n=0$ and $\lim_{n→∞}f(z_n)=w$. Show that more is true: For any fixed $δ>0$, and any $w∈C−\{0\}$, there exists $z$ with $0<|z|<δ$ and $f(z)=w$.

My Try:

By the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, we can say that given $w∈C−\{0\}$ and a neighborhood of $0$ there is $z$ in that neighborhood, such that $f(z)$ is close to $w$.

Here, we need $e^{1/z}=w$. i. e. $\displaystyle z=\frac{1}{\log w}$. But, how do I set $\displaystyle 0<\Bigg|\frac{1}{\log w}\Bigg|<δ$ for a given $\delta>0$ and $w\in C−\{0\}$? Can anyone please help me to complete the proof?

Comment: Can you show that given any $K < +\infty$, that for every $w \in \mathbb{C}\setminus 0$ there are $z$ with $e^z = w$ and $\lvert z\rvert > K$?

Comment: I don't understand how to show it. Is there a particular theorem to use?

Comment: No theorems, just some properties of the exponential function. If we drop the restriction on $\lvert z\rvert$, can you show that there is a $z$ with $e^z = w$?

Comment: Yes. I can find $z$ if there is no restriction. I have shown it in my try of the OP. Actually I have the problem of showing that restriction.

Comment: What do you know about the set $\{ z : e^z = w\}$?

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $\mathrm{e}^{\zeta}=w$, then $\mathrm{e}^{\zeta+2k\pi i}=w$, for all $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Thus, $\,\,f\left(\frac{1}{\zeta+2k\pi i}\right)=w$, for all $k\in\mathbb Z$.